# Difference between `CMPXCHG8B m64` and `CMPXCHG r/m64, r64`?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, atomic, instruction-set, compare-and-swap

According to https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

They are different in zen4

- LOCK CMPXCHG, Ops=5, Latency=9
- LOCK CMPXCHG8B, Ops=15, Latency=10

instruction reference: // can't see any difference

- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg8b:cmpxchg16b
- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmpxchg

Comment: `cmpxchg8b` and `cmpxchg16b` operate on pairs of registers.  Plain `cmpxchg` operates on only one register.

Comment: Normally you'd only use `cmpxchg8b` in 32-bit mode; 64-bit mode makes `cmpxchg m64` available which is simpler and more efficient.  If 64-bit mode didn't exist, perhaps AMD would have added more specialized hardware to speed up merging a pair of registers into a 64-bit value to CAS with, but touching more architectural registers is inherently more expensive since it's more dependency tracking.  A single uop can only have a limited number of inputs.

Comment: @PeterCordes `cmpxchg8b` might still be useful e.g. in ABIs with 32 bit pointers.  Saves you the hassle of joining and splitting the two parts.